# For Next.js, is it possible to set up multiple entries for each page which uses the dynamic route?

Tags: next.js, webpack-5

I have a dynamic route set up for Next.js. The folder structure is [lan]/[...slug].tsx, and I know that in Webpack we can set up multiple entries for each page. In Next.js, we can also customize the Webpack setting with the below:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack (config) {
    return merge(config, {
      entry () {
        return config.entry().then((entry) => {
          return Object.assign({}, entry, { myentry: './test'
          })
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am curious about how I can set up Webpack to make each page one entry point with the slug as the chucnk ID name, because I use the dynamic route here.

I try to add the entry point one by one. Yes, it can work.
I want to figure out how I can make it happen with a dynamic route.

Or is that possible to export all resource for page one by one? I mean, I expect the output of the export to be like below folder structure:

E.g., for URL /en/blog/life-blog, I want all static files to be exported to the *en-blog-life-blog folder*, so each page can have its own static HTML content.

Comment: Re *"chucnk ID name"*: Do you mean *"[chunk](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chunk#Noun) ID name"*?

Comment: oh, yes, just wrong spelling here, should be  chunk ID name